# Why this error is showing 'Error Code: 1146. Table 'sakila.t' doesn't exist'?

Tags: mysql

I want to find the names of actors who did perform in maximum number of films using DERIVED table. How this error is coming out?

my query

```
select actor from
(
    select distinct(actor.first_name) as 'actor',count(film.film_id) as 'film_count' from actor
    join film_actor on film_actor.actor_id=actor.actor_id
    join film on film.film_id=film_actor.film_id
    group by actor
    order by film_count
) as t
where film_count=(select max(film_count) from t);
```

[my query + error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgMEH.png)

[database sakila](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1scE.png)

Comment: add your query as text

Comment: select actor from
(
 select distinct(actor.first_name) as 'actor',count(film.film_id) as 'film_count' from actor
 join film_actor on film_actor.actor_id=actor.actor_id
 join film on film.film_id=film_actor.film_id
 group by actor
 order by film_count
) as t
where film_count=(select max(film_count) from t);

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT actor FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT(actor.first_name) AS 'actor',
    COUNT(film.film_id) AS 'film_count' 
    FROM 
    actor 
    JOIN 
    film_actor 
    ON film_actor.actor_id=actor.actor_id 
    JOIN 
    film ON 
    film.film_id=film_actor.film_id 
    GROUP BY actor.first_name 
    ORDER BY film_count 
    ) AS t  order by film_count desc
LIMIT 1
```

You cannot refer to table 't' created inside subquery directly in a `where` clause outside the subquery. instead use the above query. i have ordered the result by film_count column in descending order and taken the first row to get actor with largest number for film_count